# How to setup USB wireless card as AP hotspot (tl-wn725n)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, android, hot-spot

I tried to set up hotspot for my android mobile on my ubuntu 12.04. follow the instruction of here: 
'http://thenewbieblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/wifi-hotspot-setup-on-ubuntu/'  
However it does not work for the old onboard card could not support the ap mode. I bought a TL usb wireless card for it, and installed the driver, then black list my onboard card in blacklist as 'blacklist iwlwifi'.
But when I called ap-hotspot configure, the same error appeared as:
Your wireless card does not support Access Point mode 
What should I do next?
Here is the out put of iwconfig

```
wlan1     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I think the wireless card works well but there are something wrong with the configure  files...

Comment: I am so glad to get another method to setup two wireless card working for the hotspot.<br/> But I need AP for the hotspot that is why I bought a new usb card...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out to verify that it works. No hostapd and no access-point script. Instead of an "access-point" this sets up an "ad-hoc" network using network-manager. "ad-hoc" uses wireless abg instead of wireless-n.

Sharing wifi from a wireless router to my laptop internal card (wlan0) to an acer chromebook from the laptop usb (wlan1). For some reason I couldn't get my internal card (wlan0) to broadcast.

- Click on the network-manager indicator and select "create new wifi
  network" from the dropdown menu.
- I first selected the wlan1 card and named the network "pineapples".
- I have it set to ad-hoc and under ipv4 it's set to "share connection
  with other computers", no security.

Also, as "pineapples" was resolving on the laptop, I clicked to connect to "pineapples" on the chromebook as soon as the network appeared; then, the two computers connected to each other.

- If the laptop drops or doesn't connect to "pineapples", it should
  still be listed as an available network from the network-manager
  dropdown list. Click to connect to the "pineapples" network on the laptop and while it is resolving, connect to "pineapples" from the other device.

At first, I had no access to the internet or any websites but I clicked on my wlan0 network to reset the connection to the router and now both computers have internet.

Comment: You may need to run `sudo apt-get purge ap-hotspot` if the configuration from that interferes with setting this up. Some cards don't support access-point mode so this is the way to set up a hotspot *without* using access-point mode.

Comment: I got lost from your method...